# Can I contract with an irregular perfect stem in v?

Tags: verbs, perfect-tense, contraction, syncopated-perfect

I know that if I have a regular first conjugation verb, I can contract some forms.
For example, *amavisti* and *amaverunt* can become *amasti* and *amarunt*, and I have come across such forms repeatedly.

Can I contract the V away if the perfect stem is irregular but still comes with a V?
For example, I was thinking of *lavisti* and *adiuvisti* becoming *lasti* and *adiusti*.
I have never seen such forms for irregular perfect stems although they are easy to form by analogy.
Can such forms be found in the Latin literature?
A quick search turned up nothing, but I only checked a couple of forms for a couple of verbs.
Is there perhaps a source that suggests that such contraction is wrong if they are nowhere to be found?

Comment: What do you mean by irregular? In *lavisti, adiuvisti* the difference is that the *v* is part of the verb stem, rather than part of the perfect suffix. I doubt that such a *v* could be elided, but I don't actually have any evidence.

Comment: Good question! Do you consider *-ere* to be something other than a contraction? If so, you might want to exclude that in the title, because *-ere* is not what you're after. @TKR Vide infra! Or do you think *consuesti* is something else?

Comment: @TKR, by irregular I mean any verb whose perfect stem is formed differently than those of *amare* or *audire*. I know that the 'v' is stronger in irregular perfects in the sense that is indeed (typically, at least) part of the stem, not just a perfect suffix.

Comment: @Cerberus I edited the question slightly to emphasize that I'm interesting in contract the 'v' away, not other kinds of contractions. (If this is what you asked.)

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta: Perfect!

Comment: @Cerberus I don't see how *consuesti* is any different, as there too the elided *v* is part of the perfect suffix, not the stem. (Btw 3pl. *-ere* is not a contraction of anything, just an alternate personal ending.)

Comment: @TKR: OK but is the -v- in *iuvi* part of the root or is it the perfect -v-? Considering *iutum*, I would be inclined to say it is the perfect -v-. As to -ere, I tried to find more information about its origin, and it seems it isn't a contraction of -erunt, as you say. But I still don't understand how it came to be. This source says it contains the "impersonal" r also found in the infinitive and the passive forms:

Comment: https://books.google.nl/books?id=O7z4Sl-SgFEC&pg=PA275&lpg=PA275&dq=latin+ere+erunt+origin&source=bl&ots=rMJkZtZCbs&sig=ucQuBQ1mNBKmszhFVIkB5A8_Wp0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjd2eKX8afMAhVElxoKHeW3AzIQ6AEIKDAD#v=onepage&q=latin%20ere%20erunt%20origin&f=false

Comment: @TKR: I've turned this into a question: http://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/781/what-is-the-origin-of-the-3rd-person-plural-perfect-ending-%C4%93re

Comment: @Cerberus, the *v* of *iuvi* appears in the present stem *iuvo*, so it must be part of the root. Consonantal *v* can be lost between a rounded vowel and another consonant, which is why it doesn't appear in *iutum*: cf. *motum* from *moveo*.

Comment: @TKR: Okay, I believe you. (But the question did not explicit say the -v- could not be the perfect -v-, as long as the result is irregular, so I think my answer is still not disqualified by this.)

Comment: @Cerberus, you understood the question correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is not normally done, except if the perfect stem ends on *-ev/iv/av-*, because only then does one get the familiar contracted sequences *-esti/isti/asti*. The sequence *-usti* would look too unfamiliar as a perfect contraction, I think, not to mention *-urunt*.

I believe irregular perfecta on *-evi/ivi/avi* are mostly irregular because the verb has a present suffix in the present tense, like *-sc-*.

One example: the forms **consuerunt, consuesti,** and **consuestis** are common. *Consuesco* has an irregular perfect on *-v-*, *consuevi*. In the form *consuesti* it can be seen that *consuesco* does not have an alternative perfect *consui*, for otherwise it would have been *consuisti*, not *consuesti*.

Marcus Tullius Cicero, *Epistulae ad Familiares* 6.7.6.7:

> ... sed utrique rei excusationem tuae vitae consuetudo dat. nam quod ita **consuesti** pro amicis laborare, non iam sic sperant abs te sed etiam sic imperant tibi familiares.

There are also forms from *-io* present stems, like *quaesisti* and *adisti*, but those are are probably best considered contractions of *quaesiisti* and *adiisti*, not of *quaesivisti* and *adivisti*, because *quaesirunt* and *adirunt* do not exist.

Answer (score 4):

#### V can be lost when it acts as a perfect "suffix" (not found in the present stem)

[Cser 2016](http://real-d.mtak.hu/896/7/dc_1106_15_doktori_mu.pdf) gives the rule that *-v-* cannot be lost when it is "part of the lexical makeup of the verb" ("Aspects of the Phonology and Morphology of Classical Latin", p. 117), agreeing with [TKR's suggestion in the comments](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/779/can-i-contract-with-an-irregular-perfect-stem-in-v#comment1565_779). In other words, *-v-* usually isn't lost when it is found in the present stem as well as in the perfect stem of the word, which means that *lavisti* and *adiuvisti* would not be expected to have *v*-less  variant forms.

Likewise, *cavi* and *favi* from *caveo* and *faveo* do not show V-less contracted forms (Lindsay, "A Short Historical Latin Grammar", 1915, page 194).

When *-v-* appears as a "suffix"<sup>1</sup> marking the perfect stem, it might or might not be able to be deleted: this isn't completely predictable based on the form, it also seems to depend on the lexical identity of the verb.  Cser says that *cerno* has *v*-less variants alongside the forms built on *crēv-,* but *sperno* has only *sprēv-* perfect forms.

*V*-deletion is possible not only for some verbs with *-ēvī/-īvī/-āvī* perfects, but also for some verbs with *-ōvī* perfects; Cser gives the example of *nōsco* with the forms *nōvērunt*~*nōrunt* and *nōvisse~nōsse.*

#### *adiuvo*

As Cerberus's answer implies, we don't generally see syncope/syllabic contraction of *-ui-/-ue-* in the perfect (as in *metuisti* or *metuerent* from *metuo*); based on that, I didn't expect to find forms with contraction for *adjuvo.* However, surprisingly, [Lewis and Short](https://logeion.uchicago.edu/adiuvo) says that some contracted forms are actually attested for this verb:

> adjŭro or adjuero = adjuvero, Enn. ap. Cic. Sen. 1, 1: adjuerit = adjuverit, Ter. Phorm. 537

By the way, spelling variation between -uv- and -u- before a vowel is not only found in the perfect, but also occasionally in other contexts. It's unclear to what extent a contrast between /uw/ and /u/ was actually possible in Latin; it has been observed that the spelling -uv- in Latin (that is, syllabic V followed by non-syllabic V) appears almost exclusively in contexts where the use of a single letter V would create a spelling with ambiguous pronunciation (namely, a. when followed by syllabic I and a vowel, where the spelling VI+vowel could be misread as /ujj/+vowel; b. when word-initial, where the spelling V+vowel could be misread as /w/, c. when preceded by consonantal I, where the spelling IV could be misread as /iw/) ("[The cycle without containment: Latin perfect stems](http://lingphil.mit.edu/papers/steriade/Steriade2012LatinPerfect.pdf)", by Donca Steriade, 2012, page 62).

#### Violations of this rule apparently exist, but seem fairly marginal

The rule that Cser gives is sometimes violated for verbs with *-ōvī* perfects: *moveo, mōvī* and apparently also *voveō, vōvī* can lose the *v* at the end of the perfect stem, even though *v* is also found at the end of the present stems of these verbs. The *v*-less forms of these perfect stems don't seem to be common, though. Cser says that

> For *nōv-* with -*is*-class affixes, the ratio of deleted forms in the corpus I used is 96.3%, for *mōv-*
> (including prefixed forms) only 3.6%.

(p. 117)

I found mention of contracted forms of the perfect stem of *voveo* (specifically, *dēvōrō* for *dēvōverō* in the future perfect) in the first page of "[Philological Notes](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/classical-review/article/philological-notes/F2C0579448B85BE1CD1B6E973B0B6418)" in *The Classical Review,*  Volume 3, Issue 6 June 1889 , pp. 243-246, by Fred. W. Walker. Unfortunately, I can't access any more pages there. I would assume that the specific forms given there are accurate, but I'm not sure how accurate the article as a whole is, given that it seems to argue that *amavisti* had a long vowel in the penultimate syllable and that the short forms of the perfect were older than the long forms, neither of which I think has become a mainstream position.

---

1. I put "suffix" in quotation marks just because the morphological structure of Latin perfect forms can be analyzed in different ways, and it's not always easy to divide a perfect form into parts.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers explain the "what" very well; I wanted to add a bit on the "why".

According to Brent Vine (in Klein's *Handbook of Comparative and Historical Indo-European Linguistics*):

> These [forms] have their sources in phonological reductions (thus *audīstī* and the like **with regular glide loss and contraction for `/u̯/` between like vowels**), but then **induce analogical behavior in other contexts**, thus *amāstī* etc. for *amāvistī* etc. (where glide loss should not have occurred).

(Emphasis mine.)

In other words, the original phonological development was something like "VwV → V when the two vowels are the same", which happened in the fourth conjugation. This then spread by analogy to the first conjugation. (It's worth noting that the ending *-ērunt* was originally *-is-ont*, with the same *-is-* as in *-is-tis* and the like. Rhotacism turned this into *-er-ont*; the long vowel was a later development.)

Since it was already an analogical development, it makes sense that it spread to other "irregular" forms as well, such as Cerberus's *consuēstī* and Sumelic's *nōrunt*. But it was never truly universal or predictable outside the fourth conjugation, where Quintilian calls *-ivisse* [annoyingly pedantic](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/9187/406).